# f2py does not output inout as expected

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

Why does f2py not generate a correct wrapper when dealing with inout params?

Here is an example of my function call:

```
io = 7.5
io, out1, out2, out3 = fortran_file.func(5, 2.5, False, io)
```

Here's how that might look in Fortran (example.f):

```
subroutine func(inputA, inputB, inputC, ioD, outE, outF, outG)

integer inputA
real inputB
logical inputC

real ioD, outE, outF, outG
real localH

if(.not.inputC) then
   localH= ioD
else
   localH= inputB
endif

ioD= ioD + localH
outE= inputA + 10.5
outF= inputA + 5.5
outG= inputA + 1.5
return
end
```

By default f2py marks everything here as an input, even though this is a basic example. So I create the file signature using:

```
python.exe -m numpy.f2py -m fortran_file -h sig_example.pyf example.f
```

I edit the pyf file to add the correct intent info. Then I compile using:

```
python.exe -m numpy.f2py -c sig_example.pyf example.f
```

But it keeps complaining that the f2py func only returns 3 items.

Even with io explicitly using `intent(inout)`, f2py doesn't return it.

I used the `--build-dir` option in f2py to look at the generated C code for the wrapper.
The file lists io under Parameters, but it says in/output rank-0 array(float,'f)
This tells me it knows it's supposed to be inout, but I don't get why its labeling it an array?
It also doesn't list io under "Returns" which just makes me even more confused.
The associated `Py_BuildValue` call also doesn't include io in the list of args.

Why does it seem like inout isn't supposed to be returned?
That's the whole point of inout, and for certain files it's required.

I realize this whole question is niche, but I could really use some help here. Is there a way to specify param intents inside of Python? Because I have too many files to manually edit signatures.

Comment: Show the Fortran source and the commands you use to compile it in f2py. See [mre].

Comment: I can't show the source, but I can give an example showing the same issue. I'll add in my commands too.

Comment: What makes you believe that final value of an inout argument should be returned by the Python function as a result? That wouldn't look too logical to me although I didn't study the specifications.

Comment: Try `io = np.asarray([7.5]); out, out, out = fortran_file.func(5, 2.5, False, io); print(io)`. You will get your new value. I do not think the behavior you are calling for is expected. Unless someone specified somewhere it should be the way you want, you have no reason to expect such behaviour.

Comment: Because it's both an input and output? So it needs to behave as such. Otherwise f2py would be useless for most subroutines. I'm assuming I'm just missing something simple. And no, it doesn't work with arrays either - I've already checked.

Comment: It does, you checked incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

An `intent(inout)` argument will work in a  similar way it does in Fortran. However, in Python the values of the variables in the Python environment are immutable. The Fortran function will receive a copy, it will modify it's copy and then the modified copy will be discarded by Python.

But a mutable value can be put into a container such as a NumPy array. That means

```
import numpy as np
io = np.asarray([7.5])
out, out, out = fortran_file.func(5, 2.5, False, io)
print(io)
```

will print

```
[15.]
```

with the new value modified by the function.

Comment: I was trying to use a standard array, which didn't work for whatever reason. Numpy seems to work though. I don't understand why f2py just doesn't return the value. It'd be a lot more intuitive and would work for all types - not just mutable. And it would be a closer representation of what Fortran does.

Comment: It wouldn't, really not.

Comment: Good counterpoint. You don't need to use arrays for subroutines in Fortran, so yes.

Comment: @KylePonikiewski You simply have to consider the differences of pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.  Anyway, this is all moot. Unless someone somewhere promised that it will work as you would like, there is nothing to be done. It works as intended, just differently than you would like. That's all.

Comment: I'm attempting this solution with my code, and the function doesn't expect an input. Even though it was marked as inout in the pyf file. So unfortunately this is still unsolved.

Comment: We cannot help you with code we cannot see. Ser [ask] and [mcve].